# Extending ASP.NET MVC 2 Model Binder to work for 0, 1 booleans

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I've noticed with ASP.NET MVC 2 that the model binder will not recognize "1" and "0" as `true` and `false` respectively. Is it possible to extend the model binder **globally** to recognize these and turn them into the appropriate boolean values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something among the lines should do the job:

```
public class BBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value.AttemptedValue == "1")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (value.AttemptedValue == "0")
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

and register in `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(bool), new BBinder());
```

Comment: What are your thoughts on using `IModelBinder` vs `DefaultModelBinder`?

Comment: @Josiah, my thoughts are that with `DefaultModelBinder` I have one less case to worry about (the default case). If I use IModelBinder I will have to also handle the case where the value equals True or False and this case is already handled by the default model binder, so it's DRYer.

Comment: Do I have to explicitly declare that I wish to use `BBinder` or will it happen as part of the Default?

Comment: @jocull, see the last line of my post. That's what you should put in the `Application_Start` method of your `Global.asax` and that's what associates the custom model binder with the boolean type.

Comment: Excellent, just wasn't sure if that was the ticket or not. Thanks!

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - thank you. It does seem like a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this link](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/12/custom-model-binders-in-mvc-3-with-imodelbinder/). It apparently works in MVC2.

You could do something like (untested):

```
public class BooleanModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        ValueProviderResult value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        // do checks here to parse boolean
        return (bool)value.AttemptedValue;
    }
}
```

Then in the global.asax on application start add:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(bool), new BooleanModelBinder());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I wanted to ignore the or redefine the default cases, this would be the solution I used.