# MVC Modelbind int to bool?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

A previous developer created a model with a bunch of properties for our company API, which includes:

```
public bool? SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

The company API states that 0, 1, true, false are all valid values for this property to be passed.

Our test application passes in the value of "true" or "false."  However, a client of ours has started using our API and is passing 0 or 1, but model binding is saying that:

```
The value '0' is not valid for SomeProperty.
```

Unfortunately, he is unable to go back and switch it to "true" or "false" due contract issues.

Is there a way to accept 0, 1, true, and false for this property without effecting all the other models in the API?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to create a custom model binder. [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786591/extending-asp-net-mvc-2-model-binder-to-work-for-0-1-booleans)

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) in the above [comments:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078635/mvc-modelbind-int-to-bool#comment44536081_28078635)

> You need to create a custom model binder. [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786591/extending-asp-net-mvc-2-model-binder-to-work-for-0-1-booleans)