# Custom model binding for a particular property in a strongly-typed model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I could use [a custom model binder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4786712/3959480) to bind a `0` and `1` to a `false` and `true` in this action:

```
[IntToBoolBinder]
public virtual ActionResult foo(bool someValue) {
}
```

But now suppose the argument is a strongly-typed model:

```
public class MyModel {
  public int SomeInt { get; set; }
  public string SomeString { get; set; }
  public bool SomeBool { get; set; }          // <-- how to custom bind this?
}

public virtual ActionResult foo(MyModel myModel) {
}
```

The request will contain an `int` and my model expects a `bool`. I could write a *custom model binder for the entire `MyModel` model*, but I want something more generic.

Is is possible to custom bind a particular property of a strongly-typed model?

Comment: If the property is bool, why are you not using `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SomeBool)`? Why would the request contain an `int`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't want `&foo=True` because my users play around with the query string trying different combinations. When it's an int they don't.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make a custom binding to it can look like this:

```
public class BoolModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
                                         PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
        {
            Stream req = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream;
            req.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string json = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();

            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

            string value = data[propertyDescriptor.Name];
            bool @bool = Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(value));
            propertyDescriptor.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, @bool);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
        }
    }
}
```

But MVC and WebAPI int conversion to bool (field names must be the same) and do not need anything extra to write, so I do not know if you need the code above.

Try this demo code:

```
public class JsonDemo
{
    public bool Bool { get; set; }
}

public class DemoController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Demo(JsonDemo demo)
    {
        var demoBool = demo.Bool;

        return Content(demoBool.ToString());
    }
}
```

And send JSON object :

```
{
  "Bool" : 0
}
```

Comment: So this will only bind the bool properties and leave alone all the others?

Comment: Yes, other properties will be bind with default binding

Comment: What you mean "do not need anything extra to write" ? Is there something automatic being done?

Comment: Yes, there is an automatic mechanism for this. When you send 0 or 1 and JSON framework then converts it to bool. JSON Model - {"Test": 1}, C# Model  - public class Test {public bool Test {get; set;}

Comment: I added demo for this. Check please

Comment: But remember to set Content-Type to application/json in your Ajax request

Comment: My request is not AJAX, so that doesn't apply to me. But your binder is very nice!

Comment: Your answer is *very very* good. But it is for AJAX, and my request comes in as a non-AJAX POST. :) I hope someone else will post a non-AJAX answer.

Comment: Yes, but this binder is for MVC project :) but for me the best thing that I could help you :)